# HTMLInputElement has no method 'parent'

Tags: jquery

I have 2 forms on my page which are very similar.

I'm doing simple validation in jquery to check that each field has a value before using ajax to send the data on to the php handler that uses the data.

Because of the similarities between the forms, I'm not able to know which form was submitted, so I thought I'd try differentiating by an id on the form container div

```
<div name="contactform2" class="form">
    <div width="100%" class="con2">

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="first_name" class="span4">

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="email" class="span4">

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="telephone">Contact Number *</label>
        </div>
        <input  type="text" name="telephone" class="span4">

        <div class="lable">
            <label for="comments">Message *</label>
        </div>
        <textarea  name="comments" rows="8" class="span4"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
</div>
```

The only difference between the forms, really, is that one has a `<select>` in it and the other doesn't.

My jquery looks like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    var parentname = this.parent('div').attr('name');
    console.log('Form used: ' + parentname);

    var fname = 0,
        email = 0,
        tel = 0;
        comm = 0;

    // Validate data
});
```

I think maybe I got my selector wrong here as I normally select by id/class/tagname so I'm not even sure it's valid.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: Even if you switch `this` for `$(this)` you won't get the result you want, because the parent `div` of the submit button doesn't have a name attribute. Name attributes aren't meant to be used for `div`s, they're for form and input elements. Speaking of which, your form should be wrapped in a `<form>` element. You could then use `$(this).closest('form').attr('name')` - which is much more ideal.

Comment: @ahren, true. Specially because we can't see where the `<form>` element is. He is using a `div` with classname `form` which it is not the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) is a jQuery function, you forgot to wrap `this` in `$()`.

```
var parentname = $(this).parent('div').attr('name');
console.log('Form used: ' + parentname);
```

You should take a look at `.closest()` instead.

Comment: @AspiringAqib, yes. I can rephrase it as "method" if you prefer :)

Comment: HAHAHAHA I derped really hard that time. I thought something looked wrong when `this` didn't italicize and go bold like it should when it's done properly. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alexander its traversing finding method which has expression as arguments

Comment: @DipeshParmar, how's that relevant in the conversation?

Comment: @Ortund - `this` is just as proper as `$(this)`. The difference is one is an HTMLElement and the other is a jQuery object. Any syntax highlighter will highlight `this`.

Comment: @AspiringAqib : Do you have a regular habit of popping around and poke others unnecessarily? Duh!

Comment: @Alexander : +1 Good find!