# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined

Tags: jquery

**NOTE** Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997313/htmlinputelement-has-no-method-parent#14997331) for a bit of background...

So my (very basic) form validation is working - sort of.

When checking the input value for the email address field, I want to make sure that the email address has a value (i.e. is not blank) and contains `@` and `.` characters so I did this...

```
<div width="100%" class="con1">

    <div class="lable">
        <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
    </div>
    <input  type="text" name="email" class="span4">

</div>

<script>

$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    var parentname = $(this).parent('div');
    console.log('Form used: ' + parentname);

    var email = 0,

    // Validate email
    if ($('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val() == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter a valid email address');
    }
    else
    {
        if (($('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val().contains('@')) && ($('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val().contains('.')))
        {
            email = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Please enter a valid email address');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

It looks a little weird but complexity as mentioned in the linked question above required me to think a little differently with my selectors.

Basically `$('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email')` is the same as writing (in the case I'm using `$('.con1 #email')` as the selector which I believe to be correct based on my HTML structure.

I tried working with `$('.' + parentname.attr('class').child('#email')` but then kept getting an error that said the element had no method 'child'

I wrote this based on a previous form I'd created where I'd used the same principle in effect, to block emails coming from yahoo.com because I was getting a lot of spam from there:

```
if ($("#contact-email").val().contains("yahoo.com")) {
     $(".errmsg").text("Domain yahoo.com has been banned due to excessive spam, please use another domain.");
}
else
{
    email = 1;
}
```

While the 2nd sample that I've pasted here works, the first one that validates the email field more thoroughly keeps returning this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined

I can't understand how this could work in one site and not another. I feel like I'm missing something so would appreciate it if anyone can see what that might be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, if you comment out the else block and enter an empty email address, does your alert statement get called?  `if ($('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val() == '')`

Comment: store `$('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val()` in a variable and debug it..

Comment: That's another confusing thing. All field (first name, contact number, email, comments) are validated in the same way and I haven't actually entered data into any of the fields in any of my tests so far, so the alert should be hit regardless, not this check - yet

Comment: Shouldn't the `<input>` have an `id` of `"email"` to allow this selector? `$('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email')`

Comment: @WheretheresaWill you are absolutely right. Added in id attributes on all my inputs and it works as expected now. Please write an answer for your karma :)

Comment: Glad it helped, and yep I'll post it as an answer - I've only got 86 rep so need all the points I can get thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  elements should have an `id="email"` to allow the selector:

```
$('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email')
```

Comment: Don't suppose you can suggest why I'm getting an error that says `Object me@this.com has no method 'contains'` when I enter an email address as well?

Comment: Ah yes - sorry I didn't spot this.  `Contains()` is for use with jquery objects and not strings.  For strings you'd have to use `.indexOf("@")` which returns the location of the character within the string, or `-1` if it isn't present.  Try something like:  `if( ($('.' + parentname.attr('class') + ' #email').val().indexOf('@') > 0)`